# Command composer require symfony/apache-pack doesn't create .htaccess file

Tags: symfony, symfony4

When I execute the command:

```
composer require symfony/apache-pack
```

It doesn't create an `.htaccess` file as it is cited in the documentation [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html).

How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: For avoidance of doubt, could you add a link to the documentation you are looking at?

Comment: The exact output you get when running the command would also help - if I run it I end up with an `.htaccess` file in the `public\` dir.

Comment: I added the link to the documentation .

Comment: when I run the command it seems working but when I search in my project I dont find the htaccess file.

Answer (score 7):

If apache-pack is installed in your project and you later remove the .htaccess file from the /public directory, running `composer require apache-pack` will not re-install the .htaccess file.
**You must first remove apache pack.**

So, first run `composer remove symfony/apache-pack`

And then run `composer require symfony/apache-pack`

As explained here : https://github.com/symfony/recipes-contrib/issues/676#issuecomment-519959252

Comment: If you are not asked to run the recipe, check you have symfony/flex installed as well.  If not, try adding it with "composer req symfony/flex" then try the remove / require again.

Comment: I had to run those commands twice to make it work

Answer (score 1):

The solution is :

1-removing symfony/apach-pack from required in compoer.json
2- run command

> composer update

which delete  apach-pack  from project.

3-run again the command for installing apach-pack as cited in the documentation [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html):

> composer require symfony/apache-pack

4- when asked this question :

> Do you want to execute this recipe?

type :

> Yes

5- That's it now the file .htaccess exists

Comment: What if symfony/apache-pack doesn't ask you if you want execute a recipe?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue as Dan where composer was not asking me to execute any recipes.  it turns out I needed to install Symfony Flex which wasn't present in my microkernel application.  I used "composer req symfony/flex" to install it and then afterwards a remove/require of symfony/apache-pack asked me to run the recipe.  You can also type "composer recipes" to see your recipes and their status, once flex is installed.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to remove the package and reinstall it but didn't work so I tried to execute the same commands on another console and it works for me

- git bash terminal : didn't work
- windows terminal: it works (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/)