# symfony 5 is not serving routes other than /

Tags: symfony, routes

i am following the tutorial and symfony is not working for routes other than /. I am using a xampp stack to serve html and get a 404 error in  the logs. i tried putting the route in routes.yaml and using annotations @Route("/brand/new", name="brand_new").what else should I try?

Answer (score 2):

You are probably missing a `.htaccess` file which redirects requests to the `index.php` front controller.

You can install a recommended version of it through a flex recipe:

```
composer require symfony/apache-pack
```

Further information: https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html

Comment: I tried that composer require... and it didn’t make a .htaccess file.

Comment: Do you have symfony/flex installed? If not you can create the `.htaccess` file by hand following the instructions at the symfony web server config docs.

Comment: Thanks! I got it working and I'm off to the races!

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer at [Command composer require symfony/apache-pack doesn't create .htaccess file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56594679/command-composer-require-symfony-apache-pack-doesnt-create-htaccess-file)

first do composer remove... then composer require...